# Духи - имя собирательное?

Tags: части-речи

Здравствуйте! "Духи" — это имя собирательное или нет?

Comment: Ставлю минус за полное игнорирование знаков препинания (все ошибки исправила)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ВЕЩЕСТВЕННОЕ
http://www.yarus.aspu.ru/?id=419  
 Веще´ственные имена´ существи´тельные – это существительные, употребляемых для обозначения однородных по составу веществ, поддающихся делению или измерению (но не счёту, т.е. неисчисляемые), служащие названиями:
     – продуктов питания (например, молоко, сахар, сметана);
     – злаковых культур (например, рис, пшеница, рожь);
     – овощей (например, картофель, морковь, капуста);
     – ягод (например, рябина, клубника, крыжовник);
     – лекарственных средств (например, баралгин, но-шпа, валерьянка);
     – твёрдых, жидких, сыпучих веществ, материалов (например, кожа, пластик, глина);
     – тканей (например, бархат, шёлк, хлопок);
     – ископаемых (например, нефть, мрамор, уголь);
     – металлов и других химических элементов (например, золото, сталь, бром).
Вещественные имена существительные обычно не имеют соотносительных форм по числу и употребляются только в единственном числе (например, золото, молоко, крыжовник) или только во множественном числе (например, духи, сливки, опилки).

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы не мнение спрашиваете, а занимаетесь "словоблудием".Доказываем с когнитивной точки зрения.Собирательные существительные называют объекты, значимые только в своей совокупности и приобретающие в этой совокупности новое качество. Их представляют как совокупность РАЗНЫХ предметов: листва-совокупность листьев осины, берёзы, дуба и т.д. Опилки - множество одинаковых частиц.

Comment: Вещественные существительные обозначают то, из чего изначально состоит или создаётся объект (и его детали) и то, что нужно для дальнейшего продления его бытия, а также отходы его материального существования.Опилки - мельчайшие частицы материала, образующиеся при обработке пилой.Древесные опилки, металлические опилки, это не совокупность частиц дерева, а именно материал, состоящий из большого количества этих частиц,( они одинаковы, в отличие от собирательного сущ.)

Comment: Духи-ароматическая жидкость на спирте, парфюмерное средство - вещественное. Это же не совокупность чего-то, почему оно должно быть собирательным?

Comment: жаль иностранцев,например англоязычных (Собирательные существительные в английском языке

Существительные, которые обозначают совокупность лиц, предметов, явлений, называются собирательными существительными.

В британском английском собирательные существительные могут употребляться как существительные единственного числа (если вся совокупность лиц, предметов, явлений, представляется как одно целое), либо как существительные множественного числа (если такая совокупность представляется как группа отдельных лиц, предметов, явлений).

Comment: собирательные (например: class – класс, jury – жюри, army – армия, team – команда)

Comment: Да, классы существительных в русском и английском различны. Но если англичанин не собирается заниматься русской лингвистикой - ему это не нужно, ему важна семантика, а не морфология. Плохо, когда русские студенты-филологи и лингвисты в этом не разбираются.

Comment: в других языка тоже не как в русском,а мозг у людей одинаковый.

Comment: >в других языка тоже не как в русском,а мозг у людей одинаковый.

@Student, мозг у людей не одинаковый и думают по-английски и по-русски по разному. Отсюда например, разный синтаксис и интонации предложений.